# Date and DateTime storing in database

Tags: .net, date, cloud

There is a case when we have to store date in the database. We are talking about a cloud application made in .net core, which is a web API. There is a UI web where users may select dates.

API is working with UTC DateTime. Every DateTime object is converted to UTC when it hits any endpoint.
So `2020-8-7T10:00:00+0200` is converted to `2020-8-7T08:00:00Z` and then the UTC date is saved into database. It is quite good working solution in the most cases.

However there is one case which is a little bit confusing. If we are saving **only date** (we do not care about time) then it looks like this `2020-08-07T00:00:00+0200` then in DB `2020-08-06T22:00:00`.

My question is if we do not care about time should we save date as UTC like in second example, so date in database will be basically a day before? Or just save 2020-08-07T00:00:00?

Answer (score 1):

Universal time should not be manipulated, thats the whole point of converting it to UTC, so it's globally universal. I would keep it as "day before" because if you would need it, you want to convert it back to your local time.

I don't know what is your design. If you look at the date when something was added and you wont care about time you dont have to convert it to utc. You can add it the way it is or set the time always as midnight  :

```
var date = new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day, 0, 0, 0);
```

If you for some reason have to convert it to utc(when time doesn't metter) you could before converting to utc set the time to 2:00 at night :

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2020, 08, 07);
var date = new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day, 2, 0, 0);
date = date.ToUniversalTime();
```

But you have to consider winter and summer change for your country